# Odd output from R POSIXlt

Tags: r

Can someone explain what the second d$year is not 1?

```
> d = as.POSIXlt("1900-01-01")
> d$year
[1] 0
> d$mon = d$mon + 12
> d
[1] "1901-01-01"
> d$year
[1] 0
>
```

Contrast with this:

```
> d = as.POSIXlt("1900-01-01")
> d
[1] "1900-01-01"
> d$year
[1] 0
> d$year = d$year + 1
> d
[1] "1901-01-01"
> d$year
[1] 1
>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`POSIXlt` objects are lists.  You changed the `mon` element of the list.  That does not change the `year` element of the list.

```
d <- as.POSIXlt("1900-01-01")
unclass(d)
d$mon <- 12
unclass(d)
```

If you want your change to alter any/all of the other list elements, convert it to `POSIXct` then back to `POSIXlt`.

```
unclass(as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(d)))
```

Answer (score 3):

It is because you are directly manipulating the elements of a list (`POSIXlt` object).  When printed, it is normalized to a "real" date, but when individual elements are accessed, they still have the non-normalized values.

Consider
d <- as.POSIXlt("1900-01-01")

```
dput(d)
d$mon <- d$mon + 12
dput(d)
d <- as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(d))
dput(d)
```

which gives

```
> d <- as.POSIXlt("1900-01-01")
> dput(d)
structure(list(sec = 0, min = 0L, hour = 0L, mday = 1L, mon = 0L, 
    year = 0L, wday = 1L, yday = 0L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))
> d$mon <- d$mon + 12
> dput(d)
structure(list(sec = 0, min = 0L, hour = 0L, mday = 1L, mon = 12, 
    year = 0L, wday = 1L, yday = 0L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"))
> d <- as.POSIXlt(as.POSIXct(d))
> dput(d)
structure(list(sec = 0, min = 0L, hour = 0L, mday = 1L, mon = 0L, 
    year = 1L, wday = 2L, yday = 0L, isdst = 0L), .Names = c("sec", 
"min", "hour", "mday", "mon", "year", "wday", "yday", "isdst"
), class = c("POSIXlt", "POSIXt"), tzone = c("", "PST", "PDT"
))
```

Note that coercing to POSIXct and back to POSIXlt normalized it (year is 1 and mon is 0)

Comment: That makes sense, but why would they want it to do this? Why not have the months roll over into years when appropriate?

Comment: Because `POSIXlt` is an S3 class, which is a class system which is designed more for dispatch rather than for data protection (unlike some object oriented designs).  That is, you can directly manipulate parts of the class (list, really), even if that makes an "invalid" object.  It is not a function which makes a date 12 months later, it is directly taking the `mon` element of the list and adding 12 to it.  Said another way, you are not operating on the class as a whole, but directly changing one part of the object; see the `lubridate` package for a different approach.