# Modify date structure

Tags: r, date

I want to change the day part of a year-month-day structure. For example, from 1990-01-03 to 1990-01-01. Is the code below correct?

```
d<-as.POSIXlt("1990-01-03")
d$mday<-1
```

wday and yday are not changed, so the result is somewhat inconsistent. I use the result only for conversion to character strings. Other date representations I know(Date, POSIXct) are inconvenient for this task.

Comment: `lubridate::day(d) <- 1`

Comment: It's a bad idea to manipulate `POSIXlt` objects manually. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7391529/odd-output-from-r-posixlt)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use lubridate package to parse date and then subtract days

```
library(lubridate)

a=ymd("1990-01-03")
```

From [How to subtract days in R?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2254986/how-to-subtract-days-in-r)

```
a-2
```

or `day(a)=1`

Comment: There is no need in `lubridate` here. They can just do everything with `as.Date` here. And if this is a dupe- it should be closed rather adding answers to it.